# Issues with USB

Tags: windows-10, laptop, keyboard, mouse, usb-3

I have an issue with my laptop's USB 3.0 ports: When I connect a keyboard or a mouse, Windows 10 won't detect them. Even the lights or LED won't blink. Same goes with USB 2 flash drives: Windows won't detect them. And when I connect my mobile phone through a USB cable, I can't access data but mobile is getting power. (It charges) When I connect the above devices, I get a "Device Descriptor request failed" error in Device Manager. And the USB 2.0 flash drive won't show up in boot menu either.Also the USB keyboard doesn't work in BIOS menu.

However, when I connect a USB 3.0 flash drive, Windows detects it and I can access data also. What could be the issue here?

I did reinstall all drivers, tried to switch to Windows 7, and disabled fast startup and selective suspend as well.

My doubt is whether USB ports fails to deliver enough power to USB 2.0 devices or the ports itself is damaged ?.Or even worse whether the USB controller IC is damaged ??

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could describe details of your laptop hardware, what is shown in device manager (which chipset, etc), what the USBview.exe utility shows. So far it looks like you have some problem with handling USB2 section of your hardware. Does your USB2 work if you are in BIOS setup mode?

Comment: Intel(R) 7 series/C216 Chipset Family USB host controller is the chipset my laptop is having.And no USB 2.0 devices doesn't show up in BIOS menu .

Comment: Using an old USB cable and a multi meter I tested all my USB ports and found out that there is not enough current flowing.I'm getting less than 50 mA from all my ports.So the problem with my USB was related to power issues.